# How to access Javascript object's member in a forEach or for iteration

Tags: javascript

i have a object called numObj and I created a numArrary containing an array of numObj objects. 
When I try to use foreach to call its inner members, it turns out unaccessable. Why's that?

```
   var numObj = function (num) {
        return {
            num:num
        }
    }
    var numArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        numArray[i] = numObj(i);
    }
    numArray.forEach(
        function () {
            alert(this.num); //undefined
        }
    );
```

Moreover when I get deeper level of inner objects, I lose my intellisense in VS. Any idea?

Comment: i this really javascript? Dont you want to use a `for(numObj in numArray)` form?

Comment: @shishirmk: Yes, it's really JavaScript.

Comment: @ user: *"i have a object called numObj"* You do, yes, although most people would have called it a function. (It's *also* an object, because JavaScript functions are objects, but...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks just tried it in CDT console. Dint know about this format at all..

Comment: @shishirmk: No worries. :-) *"Dint know about this format..."* Well, nothing's changed *syntactically* (the OP just has a slightly unusual approach to line breaks, but quite a clean and readable one). `forEach` is just a function on arrays, added by ES5.

Answer (score 4):

The entry is passed as the first argument to the `forEach` iterator, so:

```
numArray.forEach(
    function (obj) {    // Declare the argument
        alert(obj.num); // Use it
    }
);
```

[`forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) doesn't use `this` for the entry (as, for instance, jQuery's similar function does).

Comment: Thanks Crowder,
How about for ( a in b) expression?

Comment: @user1978421: The `for-in` loop iterates over the enumerable properties of an object. It's not usually the best way to loop through an array's contents, for various reasons. More in [this other answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-a-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) and [this post on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var numArray = [{1:1},{2:2}];


   numArray.forEach(function(value,index){
         console.log(value,index,this);//{1:1},0 window
   });
```

`this` - refers to window

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6V8Ft/)